# Removing index.php with php without editing .htacces

Tags: php

I am trying to use my url to create a variable, to do so I am getting the directory as such: `$dir = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/index.php");` from my understanding this was supposed to remove the `/index.php` aspect but then i discovered it is just for removing the extension and thus fails. My links are `site.com/dir/subdir` but in the off chance someone lands on `site.com/dir/subdir/index.php` i still need to get the `subdir` variable. What is the best way to do this? It works fine with basename but if it goes to index.php then the variable becomes index.php instead of subdir. The issue with using .htaccess is that this is only done for 4 types of pages, not the whole site so I just need it to function this way on those pages.

Comment: You could `str_replace('index.php','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: I didn't think of that either, that's a good idea, Barmar's answer was more specifically for this type of issue I believe. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$dir = basename(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```